# how to print output of two echo commands side by side

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have two commands

```
echo "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |runmqsc UFISMQ |grep QUEUE | awk '{print $1}' |cut -c6-100
```

output:

```
(SYSTEM.BROKER.CONTROL.QUEUE)
(TO_UFIS)
(ATC_IN)
(BELT_IN)
(COUNTER_IN)
(FLIGHT_IN)
(OTHERS_IN)
(TRIGGER_IN)
```

another command

```
echo "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |runmqsc UFISMQ |grep IPPROCS |cut -c11-15 |sed "1 d"
```

output:

```
(3)
(18)
(2)
(2)
(2)
(2)
(2)
(2)
```

basically the two commands give queue names and the input command I want to publish the side by side like

```
(SYSTEM.BROKER.CONTROL.QUEUE)   (3)
(TO_UFIS)                       (18)
(ATC_IN)                   (2) 
(BELT_IN)                  (2) 
(COUNTER_IN)               (2)
(FLIGHT_IN)                (2) 
(OTHERS_IN)                (2)
(TRIGGER_IN)               (2)
```

Comment: your over complicate it with two commands, awk should do it. what is a sample result of `echo "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)"` ?

Comment: As @Archemar said, you're making this far more difficult than it needs to be.  Even aside from just running it once and extracting both values you need in the one run, it's clear from  looking at the reference docs for the [runmqsc display queue](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086270_.htm) command that you can tell it which fields to print.   e.g. `echo "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |runmqsc UFISMQ firstfieldname IPPROCS` (i don't know what the first field is actually called, i don't use web sphere. but it should be known to you).

Comment: stop thinking of commands as magic incantations that do something inexplicable.  instead, think of them as tools that you can understand and use in a variety of different ways if only you make some small effort to learn how to use them effectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `paste` like this:

```
paste <(command1) <(command2)
```

In your case it's:

```
paste <(echo "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |runmqsc UFISMQ |grep QUEUE | awk '{print $1}' |cut -c6-100) <(echo "dis q(*) where (IPPROCS gt 1)" |runmqsc UFISMQ |grep IPPROCS |cut -c11-15 |sed "1 d")
```

Comment: This does not keep the colors